# Using angularjs mocks without actually mocking anything

Tags: testing, angularjs, jasmine

I'm writing some test for our app, and I've included angularjs-mocks.js so I can use the nice dsl functions that come with it.

But I don't want to actually mock the $http requests, since I'm integrating this app with a client's backend that is constantly in flux, and I want to test against real responses.

What's the best (easiest) way to use the real http backend in this situation?

**EDIT:**

I've found a potential solution, which is to use this:

```
$httpBackend.whenPOST(/.*/).passThrough()
```

But as I mention below, it's not working, possibly broken? I get this error:

```
Error: Unexpected request: POST /some/url/here No more request expected
```

I've opened an issue here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1434

Comment: you could always create a mock $http to inject by creating a simple javascript that did the XHR http request, no angular mocks necessary. It's the nice thing about testing in JavaScript, you can slap together objects and inject them however you please because of dynamic typing.

Comment: Right, but the problem is that angularmocks overrides $httpBackend, which $http uses. I'm now trying to get around it with $httpBackend.whenGET(/.*/).passThrough(), but that seems either broken, or I'm not using it right.

Comment: I guess what I'm suggesting is you can use vanilla js to just create an object with all of the methods you need on it. No angular mock required.

Comment: That's true, but then I still wouldn't actually be testing the specific implementation of $http that will be doing the requests, which I've found has some unique behaviors. And that's really 50% of what I'm interested in running tests on.

Comment: You might just be better off doing integration tests with something like [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out a quick and dirty solution to the problem: Commenting out the line where $httpBackend is overridden (1365 in angular-mocks-1.0.2.js).

```
angular.module('ngMock', ['ng']).provider({
  $browser: angular.mock.$BrowserProvider,
  $exceptionHandler: angular.mock.$ExceptionHandlerProvider,
  $log: angular.mock.$LogProvider,
  //$httpBackend: angular.mock.$HttpBackendProvider,
  $rootElement: angular.mock.$RootElementProvider
}).config(function($provide) {
  $provide.decorator('$timeout', function($delegate, $browser) {
    $delegate.flush = function() {
      $browser.defer.flush();
    };
    return $delegate;
  });
});
```

This probably breaks something else, but it lets me test what I need to test, and doesn't affect the production app, so it's okay with me. Hopefully in the future there will be a built in way to do this.